# Can we infer the size of the whole universe from its expansion rate?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, observable-universe

If the universe inflated to 100 billion km in its first second, that suggests only 1/160,000 of it was observable from any point at that moment. The expansion rate slowed after that, of course, but could we do a similar calculation based on what we know of the expansion rate over time, and estimate the size of the whole universe as a multiple of the portion we can see?

Comment: why would the size of "the whole universe" be finite?

Comment: [The Big Bang did not happen at a point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point) from which the universe expanded outwards.

Comment: Oh, I thought we had some way to determine the size of the whole universe based on this Kurzgesagt video. Is the video mistaken? "The universe, which has grown to 100 billion kilometers..." I know the Big Bang didn't happen at a point, and that space isn't expanding "into" anything.
https://youtu.be/wNDGgL73ihY?t=191